# How do I show an outlook calendar in sharepoint 2013 online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, calendar, outlook

I have a shared outlook calendar in outlook 365, and I'm trying to show it on a calendar in SharePoint Online.

I've added it in the "Calendar Overlay Settings" screen, and saved it but when I view the Sharepoint calendar I see the error:

> The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme
>   'Ntlm'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Basic
>   Realm=""'

My settings are :

Outlook Web Access URL: "https://outlook.office365.com/owa"

Exchange Web Service URL: "https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx"

I've seen a few other post where people are getting a similar problem, but no solutions.

Does this work at all?

Comment: Maybe you just can't do it ? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2997170

Comment: http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/158/t/242906.aspx

Comment: any updates on this issue?

Comment: Nope - in the end I went the other direction. Create the calendar in sharepoint, then connect to it from outlook